# Add type def to data object - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Below is a simple Vue single file component that I Have created and I want to add type definition to its data function,

How can I add type info without using typescript ?

```
<template>
   <h2> {{ title }} </h2>
</template>
<script>
 export default {
 name: 'test',
 data () {
      return {
          title: 'Hello World'
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: JS is not typed, nor is VueJS. So you cannot really achieve that kind of feature beyond writting it as a string, number or alike.

Comment: In the data function it makes not that much sense to use types because JavaScript is not really centred around that concept but if you want to receive props you can ask for a type.